# What is the best way to set up a Provider base-state using Pact.Net and .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, pact, pact-net

In the (Ruby) documentation of Pact, there is the possibility to add a Provider base-state in the provider states. I'm using Pact.Net and use ProviderStateMiddleware, but I can't figure out how to set up the base-state with this implementation. Is it possible to do this and/or does anyone have any experience setting this up?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality for a base state (that I know of - Neil Campbell, the maintainer, may correct me). I would recommend implementing a method that gets called at the start of each provider state set up call that clears the datastore completely, and then sets up the base state data.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for asking. I have recently started researching pact-net, and I am also interested in guidance.

I found this [Example Workshop for .Net Core](https://github.com/tdshipley/pact-workshop-dotnet-core-v1) very helpful.

Supplementing the example [ProviderMiddleware](https://github.com/tdshipley/pact-workshop-dotnet-core-v1/blob/master/CompletedSolution/Provider/tests/Middleware/ProviderStateMiddleware.cs), we added something like the following (assuming relational db with EF):

```
private void EnsureBaseState()
{
   _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
   _context.SaveChanges();
}

private void EnsureSecondState()
{
   EnsureBaseState();

   _context.ExampleItems.Add(new ExampleItem { Id = 1, Name = "sample item" });
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is how we are currently managing multiple states, with the additional states calling a base state in the middleware.

Comment: So instead of writing data to JSON files like they are doing in the examples, you are using an in-memory EF Core database?

Comment: Hi Aaron, that's correct. Since our service used a relational database, it was easier to run contract tests with an in-memory database than to replace our DAL to read files. I believe that this guidance from pact.io is relevant:

[Pact Provider Tests](https://docs.pact.io/provider).

It says: If you can run a local, lightweight instance of your database, it is fine to use your real database. If that is impractical, you may be better off stubbing your data layer.